# How to calculate the value of the point of minima in the following graph using python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, optimization, minima

I am trying to find the value of the point of the minima(local and global doesn't matter as there is only one minima in the first graph) in the first graph.How to do that.Point of minima is marked in red.
First graph is the smoothened out version of the second graph to prevent the issue of local minimas.

[image]

I obtained graph using following steps-

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
green = cv2.imread('5.tiff',1)
a = cv2.calcHist([green],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
blurs = cv2.GaussianBlur(a,(13,13),0)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(blurs)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(a)
```

Comment: Is your data stored in an array ?

Comment: Yes , its a numpy array, let me add how I obtained the graph too.

Comment: The global minima and local minima here are not the same. The global minima is the least value in the entire graph. In this case it would be the starting of the graph where it looks like its starting form 0

Comment: Well, in that case , I am looking for that value apart from the start and end points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can define a local minima as a point where you can go neither left or right without increasing your value. Let me demonstrate this with the help of `cos()` graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1000)
y = np.cos(x * np.pi / 180)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

The values are stored in the `y` variable. At every index (except first and last), just check the 2 neighboring values, if both values are bigger then you are currently at a local minima. Here is the code :

```
local_min = []
for i in range(1, len(y)-1):
    if y[i-1] >= y[i] and y[i] <= y[i+1]:
        local_min.append(i)
print(local_min)
```

**Output:**

```
[180, 540, 900]
```

Comment: Can you help me in figuring out , how to segregate the y-component from the graph which I used as I am still quite clueless about x and y axis in my cases?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **how to segregate the y-component from the graph**. Are you asking what is the y variable in your case ? I think it should be the `blurs` variable

Comment: Yes, I got it .Thanks.